# Java Graphics Are Not Displaying

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, graphics, pong

I am trying to code the game Pong on Java but am having difficulty displaying the graphics. Nothing appears, just a blank gray default screen when I try to run the program. I am using a Mac, and am running this code on Eclipse.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

"Pong.java"

```
package pong;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Pong implements ActionListener{

    public static Pong pong;

    public int width = 700, height = 700;

    public Renderer renderer;

    public Paddle player1;

    public Paddle player2;

    public JFrame jframe;

    public Pong(){

        Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);

        jframe = new JFrame("Pong");
        renderer = new Renderer();

        jframe.setSize(width, height);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.add(renderer);

        start();

        timer.start();
    }

    public void start(){

        player1 = new Paddle(this, 1);
        player2 = new Paddle(this, 2);

    }

    public void update() {


    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        player1.render(g);
        player2.render(g);

     }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        update();

        renderer.repaint();

     }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        pong = new Pong();

    }
}
```

"Renderer.java"

```
package pong;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Renderer extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Pong.pong.render(g);
    }   
}
```

"Paddle.java"

```
package pong;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Paddle {

    public int paddleNumber;

    public int x, y, width = 100, height = 500;

    public int score;

    public Paddle(Pong pong, int paddleNumber){

        this.paddleNumber = paddleNumber;

        if(paddleNumber == 1){
            this.x = 0;
        }
        else if (paddleNumber == 2){
            this.x = pong.width - width;

        }
        this.y = pong.height / 2 - this.height / 2;

    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

    }

}
```

Comment: Try adding the renderer to the JFrame *before* setting its visibility to `true`.

Comment: Thanks that worked!